# How to resize the custom UITableViewCell to fit content?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Basically, I have a cell with 10 labels and currently I have fixed its height to 300. However, the labels might or might not have value and if the labels do not have certain value, then I need to hide them. Checking null condition for each and every label and then adjusting the height likewise is lengthy and messy. Is there any other way to achieve what I am looking for?
[image]

Comment: Use autolayout to constrain all of your labels to the table view cell. Then in your table view delegate, return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for `heightForRowAt` and `estimatedHeightForRowAt`. With these things in place, the table/cell will handle the sizing for you.

Comment: constrain all labels to tableviewcell?? Can you please elaborate this?

Comment: Read through how to use autolayout. It is what you need.  [Article on Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) and [a Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2).

Comment: @IshaBalla Have you tried to establish such a cell in storyboard? Or not yet? If so, could you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: I have uploaded the how my tableview cell looks like in storyboard.

Comment: Please check @pedrouan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of an idea, what I would suggest. I hope this could help you to find an optimised one for you.

If I would assume, your data source is like this:

```
// array of arrays of strings
var Array : [[String]] = [
     ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4"],
     ["Label1", "Label2"],
     ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4", "Label5", "Label6"],
]
```

these methods could be implemented:

```
func calculateExpectedHeight(withItemsCount: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    let titleHeight = 32.0 // this is e.g. your Layer Conf. label
    let itemHeight = 18.0 // this is for a label unit that is repeating

    return CGFloat(titleHeight) + CGFloat((Double(withItemsCount) * itemHeight)) + 12.0 //twelve is just for tuning
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let dataForThisRow = Array[indexPath.row]
    return calculateExpectedHeight(withItemsCount: dataForThisRow.count)
}
```